# Spring-boot LDAP customize UserDetails

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap, spring-boot, spring-security-ldap

I'm using LDAP authentication in spring-boot application (configuration based on annotations). I would like to customize UserDetails object. Default UserDetails implementation is **LdapUserDetailsImpl**. I would like to extend this class and add some extra iterfaces and bind into spring-security.
My config class:

```
@Configuration
protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter { 
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        AuthMethod authMethod = AuthMethod.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("auth_method"));
        switch (authMethod) {
            case LDAP:
                auth.ldapAuthentication()
                    .userDnPatterns(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.user_dn_patterns"))
                    .groupSearchBase(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.group_search_base"))
                    .contextSource()
                    .url(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.url"));
                break;
            default:
                auth.userDetailsService(userService);
                break;
        }

    }

    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource contextSource () {
        LdapContextSource contextSource= new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.url"));
        contextSource.setUserDn(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.user"));
        contextSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.password"));
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        return contextSource;
    }
}
```

UserService is custom method of authentication (it's database/jpa authentication). 
UserDetails accessor (when auth method is LDAP it's returning LdapUserDetailsImpl object):

```
    @Component("activeUserAccessor")
public class ActiveUserAccessorImpl implements ActiveUserAccessor
{
    public UserDetails getActiveUser()
    {
        return (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

My solution:

1.Create custom UserDetailsContextMapper:

```
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper() {
        return new LdapUserDetailsMapper() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
                UserDetails details = super.mapUserFromContext(ctx, username, authorities);
                return new CustomLdapUserDetails((LdapUserDetails) details, env);
            }
        };
    }
```

2.Bind UserDetailsContextMapper with LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer:

```
  auth.ldapAuthentication()
      .userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper())
      .userDnPatterns(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.user_dn_patterns"))
      .groupSearchBase(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.group_search_base"))
      .contextSource()
      .url(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.url"));
```

3.Implement CustomLdapUserDetails (only isEnabled method is changed for now). You can add some extra interfaces, methods to CustomLdapUserDetails and return extended class in ActiveUserAccessor.getActiveUser().

```
public class CustomLdapUserDetails implements LdapUserDetails {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private LdapUserDetails details;
private Environment env;

public CustomLdapUserDetails(LdapUserDetails details, Environment env) {
    this.details = details;
    this.env = env;
}

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return details.isEnabled() && getUsername().equals(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.username"));
}

public String getDn() {
    return details.getDn();
}

public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return details.getAuthorities();
}

public String getPassword() {
    return details.getPassword();
}

public String getUsername() {
    return details.getUsername();
}

public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return details.isAccountNonExpired();
}

public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return details.isAccountNonLocked();
}

public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return details.isCredentialsNonExpired();
}
}
```

Comment: I am trying to implement Ldap authentication along with JWT token, in response. Could you please help how to implement LdapUserDetailService