# Add a method for LdapUserDetailsImpl

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ldap

I would like to add a method in LdapUserDetailsImpl, which returns the ldap username with '-' before the String.

I already tried implementing an other UserDetails but was not what i was expecting.

I know that i can create an Util class and do that, but its not a good pratice.

Comment: before the start of the ~String~.  or  Spring ???

Comment: Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007674/spring-boot-ldap-customize-userdetails) answer, I changed the constructor and worked as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring-boot LDAP customize UserDetails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007674/spring-boot-ldap-customize-userdetails)