# LDAP: fetch custom values during an authentication event

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap

I have Springboot successfully authenticating against LDAP and adding to the view a `CustomUserDetails` model.

During the authentication event I would like to also bring back additional details like email, telephone and city.

According to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242165/do-we-need-to-write-customactivedirectoryldapauthenticationprovider-if-we-want-t/54242376#54242376) it is possible and I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007674/spring-boot-ldap-customize-userdetails) also addresses it.

Despite reading both these answers I am still unsure how to proceed to do this - particularly about how steps 2 and 3 from the second answer relate, and where the details like email, city and telephone are mapped?

My security class:

**Security**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/newExhibit");
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .and()
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource()
            .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
            .and()
            .passwordCompare()
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
}
```

My user object from test-server.ldif

```
dn: uid=abc123,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Tom Smith
sn: Smith
uid: abc123
userPassword: pass
mail: tom@contoso.com
mobile: +212 307 12345
st: CA
```

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007674/spring-boot-ldap-customize-userdetails) do I need to add to auth
 (a) contextsource and
 (b) userDetailsContextMapper?

Ultimately these details from ldap I would like to map to my java user class.

**UPDATE**

An updated AuthenticationManagerBuilder

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .and()
        .ldapAuthentication()
        .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
        .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
        .contextSource()
        .userDetailsContextMapper(???) // what object in here and how initalised
        .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
        .and()
        .passwordCompare()
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
        .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
}
```

Comment: You only need a customized `UserDetailsContextMapper` to retrieve and set the custom attributes. The `ContextSource` is created by how you are configuring Spring Security.

Comment: @M.Deinum what would this UserDetailsContextMapper look like?

Comment: Looking at your LDIF file,  you don't really need an custom mapper, but you might get away with the `InetOrgPersonContextMapper`, so `new InetOrgPersonContextMapper()`, probably would do the trick. As the `mail` and `mobile` properties are defined in the LDAP schema for `inetOrgPerson`. So unless you really have custom attributes you don't really need one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your LDIF file I looks like you are trying to get the properties which are defined as part of the [inetOrgPerson](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2798). Spring Security has an out-of-the-box mapper for this the [`InetOrgPersonContextMapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/InetOrgPerson.html). This will map the defined properties to an `InetOrgPerson`, which will act as the `UserDetails` needed.

To configure you just need to create a new instance and wire it to your configuration.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .ldapAuthentication()
        .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
        .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
        .contextSource()
        .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
        .and()
        .userDetailsContextMapper(new InetOrgPersonContextMapper())
        .passwordCompare()
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
        .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
}
```

This will map the properties accordingly. As you are using LDAP you don't need the `UserDetailsService` injected as it will automatically configure an `LdapUserDetailsService` underneath.